Bad query performance postgres 16
We are trying to make the step from postgres 10 to 16, we already tried a while ago to lower versions 12 or 13, but updates were added
in the machine and the poor performance we attribute to those updates.
Now we are testing on a new machine, and we have 2 virtual machines with the same resources and same configuration in postgres.conf.
The query in question is:
select  numero, mov.id, mov.tipo_movimiento,    mov.cliente_origen_id,  mov.cliente_destino_id, mov.motivo_baja,    mov.estado estado_movimiento,   mov.tipo_notificacion,  mov.fecha_movimiento,   (   select      i.id    from        industria i join clientesprecintos c on     c.id_industria = i.id   where       c.id = mov.cliente_origen_id) as industria_origen_id,   (   select  i.id    from        industria i join clientesprecintos c on     c.id_industria = i.id   where       c.id = mov.cliente_destino_id) as industria_destino_id
    from    (values (0,'13704147270')) as precintos (position,  numero)
left join lateral ( select      mp.id,      mp.estado ,     mpt.clave as tipo_movimiento,       mp.cliente_origen_id,       mp.cliente_destino_id,      mpmb.clave as motivo_baja,      tn.clave as tipo_notificacion,      fecha_ini as fecha_movimiento
    from        movimiento_piezas_rangos mpr
    join movimiento_piezas mp on        mp.id = mpr.movimiento_piezas_id
    left join notificaciones n on       n.id_movimiento_piezas = mp.id
    left join tipos_notificaciones tn on        tn.id = n.id_tipo_notificacion
    join movimiento_piezas_tipo mpt on      mpt.id = mp.tipo_movimiento_id
    left join movimiento_piezas_motivo_baja mpmb on     mpmb.id = mp.motivo_baja_id
    where       numero::bigint between mpr.desde and mpr.hasta      and mp.estado not in ('ANULADO', 'RECHAZADO')
    order by        mp.fecha_ini desc   limit 1 ) as mov on true
order by    precintos.position;

On the machine with postgres 10, the response time is approximately 750 ms.
On the machine with postgres 16, the response time goes to 4 minutes.
Reviewed documentation, it seems that there are changes from version 12.
We have made changes to the query until we found a more optimal solution for v16:
Select numero,  mov.id,  mov.tipo_movimiento,  mov.cliente_origen_id,  mov.cliente_destino_id,  mov.motivo_baja,  mov.estado estado_movimiento,  mov.tipo_notificacion,  mov.fecha_movimiento,  (select i.id from industria i join clientesprecintos c on c.id_industria = i.id where c.id = mov.cliente_origen_id) as industria_origen_id, (select i.id from industria i join clientesprecintos c on c.id_industria = i.id where c.id = mov.cliente_destino_id) as industria_destino_id 
 from (values (0,'15727625912')) as precintos (position, numero) 
 left join lateral (
    select mp.id, mp.estado , mp.tipo_movimiento, mp.cliente_origen_id, mp.cliente_destino_id, mp.motivo_baja, tn.clave as tipo_notificacion, mp.fecha_movimiento 
        from 
        (WITH mp_consulta AS (
            select mp.id, mp.estado , mpt.clave as tipo_movimiento, mp.cliente_origen_id, mp.cliente_destino_id, mpmb.clave as motivo_baja, fecha_ini as fecha_movimiento 
            from movimiento_piezas_rangos mpr 
        join movimiento_piezas mp on mp.id = mpr.movimiento_piezas_id 
        join movimiento_piezas_tipo mpt on mpt.id = mp.tipo_movimiento_id 
        left join movimiento_piezas_motivo_baja mpmb on mpmb.id = mp.motivo_baja_id 
        where 
            numero::bigint between mpr.desde and mpr.hasta and mp.estado NOT IN ('ANULADO', 'RECHAZADO')) 
            SELECT * FROM ( 
            SELECT * FROM mp_consulta 
            UNION ALL 
        SELECT * FROM mp_consulta ORDER BY fecha_movimiento DESC LIMIT 1 
            ) AS union_mp 
        ORDER BY fecha_movimiento DESC LIMIT 1) mp 
     left join notificaciones n on n.id_movimiento_piezas = mp.id 
     left join tipos_notificaciones tn on tn.id = n.id_tipo_notificacion 
 ) as mov on true 
 order by precintos.position;

We have seen

that order by and limit can lead to bad strategies, they suggest applying + 0, in our case increasing the date, but we don't see improvements either.
that the pg_hint_plan extension can be added, but the tests have not been satisfactory, possibly due to lack of knowledge on our part.

If the change were for a single query there would be no problem, but it is a large application, where we do not know how many queries we may encounter
with such a different and bad performance, or if it is the same pattern.
Initially it seems that it is some scheduler configuration, which would allow good results to be obtained without changing the SQL queries.

Please format your question better so that it is possible to make sense of your queries

Thanks for the suggestion, it is much more readable now.

Could you try a re-index for all indexes after upgrade. I think this might be the reason

More efficiently store duplicates in B-tree indexes (Anastasia Lubennikova, Peter Geoghegan). This allows efficient B-tree indexing of low-cardinality columns by storing duplicate keys only once. Users upgrading with pg_upgrade will need to use REINDEX to make an existing index use this feature

source - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/release-13.html#id-1.11.6.20.5
Anyway you need to do a through check before upgrade to ensure the system works well after upgrade, there are some behavior changes as well
Please go through release notes of each major release to find out the changes

I had already reset the indices and statistics, but that was where the problem was, my fault because I did not give more information, I had 3 indices, for the from, the to, and the interval from-to. When researching I used the until so depending on where the searched number was located it was faster or not. With this solution, the very fast ones (100 ms) are fast 500 ms and the very slow ones (3s) are fast 500 ms.
questions/39589/optimizing

Sorry I didn't quite get you
I think you are talking about new query being slow when compared to old one
Could you please try to do explain analyze for same query before and after postgres update, you will be able to spot time consuming part

What we did is change the query, as I indicate below, the problem is that the same query has a very different response in Postgres 10 and Postgres 16, with the resources being the same and therefore the configuration the same for the same important parameters.
postgres planning 10
postgres planning 16
What we are doing is breaking down the query to obtain the join(s) that make the response times significant.

Good keep optimizing
I can see many indexes with prefix idx_precintos_* used in PostgreSQL 10, could you check what type of index it is (seems like index created for partition table)
Please check if these exist in Postgres 16, if yes through some straight cases in which indexes will be used
